# Flask: How can I pass values from for loop to html with AJAX?

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I'm making a web app that checks to see if a user exist at various forums, then returns the results dynamically on web page via AJAX.

I'm using flask, which calls on the original python script.

main.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def search_form():

    x = request.form['searchinput']

    a = Vbulletin(x)

    def result_gen():
        return a.reg_ver()
    result_gen()

    for s in result_gen():
        text = s


    return render_template("index.html", text=text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the variable `text` is what i would like to dynamically display in Html as each response comes in. The way my code is written now it only displays the last item.

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            data : {
                x : $('#searchInput').val(),
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/'
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UserFind Home</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='forumsearch.js')}}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul id="navlist">
                <h1>Userfind</h1>
                <li><a class="btn" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <form method="POST" name=searchbar>
                    <ul id="navsearch">
                        <li class="search">
                            <input type="text" id="searchinput" name="searchinput" placeholder="Search for User here. Must be atleast 5 characters long.">
                        </li>
                        <li><button type="submit" class="btn-default">Submit</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <script>

            var btnContainer = document.getElementById("navlist");
            var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

            for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

            if (current.length > 0) {
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            this.className += " active";
                });
            } 
            </script>

        <p>{{ text }}</p>

        <div class="footer">
            <p>&copy;2019 Userfind</p>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've found a lot of information on how to pass a single value( or multiple values one time), but how can I pass each value from flask to html dynamically as a response is received?

Edit:
 This is the code that gets called with a.reg_ver():

```
    def reg_ver(self):

        urlfile = json.load(open("/home/vbulletin_regversion_SHORT_TESTING_dict.txt"))
        for url, url_veri in urlfile.items():
            try:
                payload = {'username': self.name, 'securitytoken': 'guest', 'do': 'verifyusername'}
                headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

                s = requests.Session()
                s.get(url, headers=headers)
                response = s.post(url_veri, headers=headers, data=payload)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
                message = soup.find('message').text
                if self.name in message:
                    result = (url, "user found!!! I SAID USER FOUND!!!")
                    yield result
                elif message == "Username is valid and not in use.":
                    result = (url, "user not found")
                    yield result
                else:
                    result = (message, "possible error")
                    yield result
```

The code checks for a user from a forum in the list, then yields the result. I pass result to flask with this:

```
def result_gen():
    return a.reg_ver()
result_gen()

for s in result_gen():
    text = s
```

Can I append to a temporary list, and dynamically add each result to html, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: AJAX should get `text` without HTML and append to HTML which is already in browser.

Answer (score 1):

`Flask` should send only `text` (or JSON) on `AJAX` requests and `AJAX` should get `text` (without HTML) and `append()` to HTML which is already in browser. So  this way it can appends new line to existing text.

Working example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="searchinput" name="searchinput">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p></p>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                    data: {x: $('#searchinput').val()},
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/',                    
                }).done(function(data){
                    $('p').append(data+"<br>");
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>''')

import datetime

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def search_form():

    print(request.form)

    data = request.form.get('x', '')
    text = str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " | " + data

    return text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

`Flask` could also check if it is really `AJAX` requests and send full HTML when it is not `AJAX`. But to keep all lines of text it would have to remeber them somehow/somewhere - ie. in file, database or cookies.

---

BTW: you had few mistakes:

- `$('#searchinput')` should have lower `i` but you have `I`.
- `AJAX` sends data as `x` - see `data: {x: $('#searchinput').val()},` but `flask` tries to get it as `searchinput`.

Comment: thank you for you help, that cleared up alot esp. regarding AJAX post. I'm editing my post to add the script i referenced as I probably didn't explain it well.

Comment: this is almost exactly what i was looking for. i need to update the list just like that but instead of using a button on the HTML, I need to call the updates on the html from python code dynamically.

Comment: @ChopLabalagun `python` runs on server and without `JavaScript/AJAX` it can only generate full page with new content - but you have to click button or link to ask server for new content. To change dynamically part of existing HTML in browser you have to use `AJAX` to get new element from server and replace it in HTML in browser. You can run `AJAX` on clicking button or link, or using javascript's `timer` to update periodically. If you have problem then create question on new page.